# Swift 2 button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to figure out how to know which cell got it's button tapped.

I have a download button in each cell, and I need to know which cell's button got pressed so I can start a download of the correct item.

I have done it before in OBJ-C using blocks, but just can't get it together in Swift 2.

Anyone out there with a bit of code to share?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use your objective-c approach (blocks == swift closures).
There is a lot of ways to do what you need.
You can detect which row was pressed with this:

```
    func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton)
{
    let touchPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPoint.zero, toView:tableView); // get the location of the button inside the tableview 
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint); // ask tableview which row is at this point 
    println(indexPath); // it's works! :)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't explain it properly, I think. The button I have is on a custom cell (ExamsTableViewCell), which need to send the tap back to the tableView so I can act on it there.